# What is the symbol that looks like parentheses with two dots under it? And what buttons do I need to press to use it?

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkE1D.png)

This is the image I could get from a Youtube video.

Comment: That's almost definitely crap on their screen, stuck pixels, IDE underlining, or some other irrelevant artifact. They're just parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It's not some symbol. These are just regular parentheses. The dots are just indicating some kind of error, for example: no arguments given.
It's the same as:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('bar')
... 
>>> foo()
bar
```